# Unicode error from CommCare export tool for MySql

Tags: mysql, excel, sqlite, export, commcare

While using the Commcare Export tool for exporting data, the data is exported correctly in the Excel File and also in SQLite DB, however when we try to export the Data in **`MySql DB`**, the export breaks and gives us the following error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(256)

(Refer attached Screenshot for the same)

The data is imported correctly into the DB until the Hindi Text is encountered. Once Hindi text is encountered, it breaks the process and gives the error.

We understand that the error may be due to the Devnagiri Text being inserted into the DB, so we tried to solve this issue by changing all the data columns to `utf8_unicode_ci`, but still the problem persists.

How can we fix this?

[image: Error Using the Commcare Export Tool for MySQL DB]

Answer (score 1):

The default mysqldb connection uses latin-1. According to the SqlAlchemy docs you can set the connection encoding directly in the connection string:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#unicode

The CommCare HQ Export Tool Docs at 
https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/CommCare+Data+Export+Tool#CommCareDataExportTool-SQLURLformats

include this string, and suggest the format

`mysql+pymysql://<username>:<password>@<host>/<database name>?charset=utf8`

(in your case `pymysql` would be `mysqldb`)

are you including the charset in that connector? If not, that should correct issues with the cursor expected latin-1 encoded text.